# Trying to use a pipe but not sure of how it extracts the previous value

Tags: elixir

Say I have something like this currently:

```
session = conn.assigns[:session]
user = User.find_by_id(session.user_id)
```

How could I use the |> sytle in this scenerio?

```
conn.assigns[:session]
|>User.find_by_id
```

How can I pass the previous calls and get the property user_id from it?

Also I have seen people using |> and I think they were also specifying the arity, how does this work?

```
some_code
|> some_function(&/2)
```

Something like that, I can't recall but I was confused when looking at it.

Comment: Are you looking at this [sample code](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#assign/3)? It'd help a lot to answer your question if you provided a bit more context.

Comment: The 1st part of my question has the context, the 2nd part was just something I was curious about.

Comment: I *wouldn't* use `|>` here, it doesn't seem like a natural progression.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would probably be better off pattern matching on the function head, and extracting the `user_id` from the assigns there, having said that you can use `Map.fetch!/2`, as in:

```
conn.assigns[:session]
|> Map.fetch!(:user_id)
|> User.find_by_id
```

But as you see the meaning of the pipe gets a bit obfuscated, as you go from a map, to a single value, to a schema result. IMO doesn't improve the readability nor the intent.

You can also use `conn.assigns.session.user_id |> User.find_by_id`.

All of these will fail if any of the intermediate fields are missing, but if you pattern match on the function head (I'm assuming it's in a controller) you can either have a fallback action set up, or have a catch all action that returns an error.

Answer (score 2):

First part - You can use pipe like this:

```
conn.assigns[:session]
|> Map.get(:user_id) # Use function from Map module.
|> User.find_by_id()
```

Second part. You're seeing [Capture operator](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#&/1-capture)

you can use it with a function that expect an anonymous function as argument (either it's a local function or a remote function from a module)

Let's take an example from [Ecto.Changeset.validate_change/3](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#validate_change/3)

so the third argument is expecting an anonymous function (validator) which it has 2 argument and you can write a private function in your schema to validate the change when pass to changeset and use it:

```
defp validate_title(field, title) do
  if title == "foo" do
    [{field, "cannot be foo"}]
  else
    []
  end
end
```

so when you're doing validate it with changeset you can do:

```
changeset = change(%Post{}, %{title: "foo"})
changeset = validate_change(changeset, :title, &validate_title/2)
```

Answer (score 2):

> How could I use the `|>` style in this scenario?

There are dozens of different approaches. The correct answer though **you don’t use pipe operator in this scenario**. It’s called *pipe operator* for the reason. It is intended to be used in *pipelines*.

Elixir core team considers using single `|>` in a statement an anti-pattern. You should instead use

```
user = User.find_by_id(conn.assigns[:session].user_id)
```

---

On the other hand, if you indeed want to use `|>` here, you might use [`Access`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Access.html#get/3) behaviour:

```
user =
  conn.assigns
  |> Map.get(:session)
  |> Map.get(:user_id)
  |> User.find_by_id()
```

Answer (score 1):

The `|>` takes whatever is above it (or to the left of it) and passes the value of that expression as the first argument to the function you call on the righthand side of the pipe. That's all the pipe does. So, your attempt at using the pipe here:

```
conn.assigns[:session]
|>User.find_by_id
```

is equivalent to:

```
User.find_by_id(
    conn.assigns[:session]
)
```

Here's another example:

```
defmodule My do
  def package({x, y}) do
    %{width: x, length: y}
  end

  def modify(map, z) do
    Map.put_new(map, :height, z)
  end 

  def go(tuple) do
    tuple
    |> package()
    |> modify(10)
  end
end
```

In iex:

```
~/elixir_programs$ iex c.exs
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.6.6) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)

iex(1)> My.go {1, 2}
%{height: 10, length: 2, width: 1}
```

In the `My.go()` definition, the `tuple` parameter variable gets assigned the argument `{1, 2}`, giving you this pipeline:

```
{1, 2}
|> package()
|> modify(10)
```

The first pipe causes `package()` to be called with the first argument of `{1, 2}`, so `package({1, 2})`, which returns

```
%{width: 1, length: 2}
```

leaving you with:

```
%{width: 1, length: 2}
|> modify(10)
```

Then the pipe causes `modify()` to be called with the first argument being `%{width: 1, length: 2}`, so `modify(%{width: 1, length: 2}, 10)`, which returns:

```
%{height: 10, length: 2, width: 1}
```

> Also I have seen people using |> and I think they were also specifying
>   the arity, how does this work?
>
> ```
>     some_code
>     |> some_function(&/2)
> ```

`&` is used for several different things.  First, `&` will create an anonymous function from an expression that you specify:

```
my_func = &(3*4)
```

That creates the anonymous function:

```
my_func = fun -> 3*4 end
```

Well, not quite.  That actually won't work because `&` requires that the expression following the `&` use at least one function parameter variable.  Function parameter variable??!  Here comes a second use of `&`.  The (unspecified) parameter variables for the anonymous function can be referred to with the names &1, &2, &3, etc. in the expression. So you have to write:

```
my_func = &(3 * &1)
```

That creates the anonymous function:

```
fn x -> 3 * x end
```

The anonymous function has arity 1 because only `&1` was mentioned in the expression.  If you mention `&1` and `&2` in the expression, then the arity of the created function will be 2:

```
iex(5)> my_func = &(IO.puts "#{&2} ... #{&1}")
#Function<12.99386804/2 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex(6)> my_func.("hello", "world")
world ... hello
```

If you mention `&1` and `&3` in the expression, omitting `&2`, you will get an error that says:

> capture &3 cannot be defined without &2.

You can also use `&` to create an anonymous function that wraps an existing function:

```
len = &Enum.count/1
len.([7,8,9])
=> 3
```

The `&` creates the anonymous function:

```
fun x -> Enum.count(x) end
```

You are required to uniquely identify the existing function by specifying its name and arity.  For local functions or imported functions, you can just write `&func_name/2` and eliminate the module name.